# Is there a better way to run a capistrano task from within rake?

Tags: ruby, rake, capistrano

I have a set of rake tasks where I need to invoke capistrano at some point.  Edwin Goei's [blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/edwingo/entry/add_custom_rake_tasks_to) suggests shelling out to capistrano via "sh".

Is there a simpler way?  It would seem you should be able to call the appropriate tasks programmatically.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I learned that using "system" is preferable to "sh" in my case as a non-zero exit code returned by "sh" causes rake to exit immediately while "system" allows it to continue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Capistrano has programmatic access to the command-line components. If you want to call them from a rake task, though, you need to do a little extra work.

```
task :deploy
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'capistrano'
  require 'capistrano/cli'

  parameters = ["deploy"] # this is an array of the strings that come after
                          # cap on the command line. e.g., 
                          # ["deploy", "-S", "revision=1024"] gives you local var
                          # revision in your deploy.rb.

  # The following is required ONLY when you run Capistrano 2+ from Rake, 
  # because Rake adds the methods from FileUtils to Object. FileUtils includes 
  # a method called symlink which interferes with Capistrano's symlink task.
  Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace.class_eval { undef :symlink }

  Capistrano::CLI.parse(parameters).execute!
end
```

Comment: Please note my comment above concerning "sh" vs "system".  It seems that capistrano executes my command on the remote server via "sh" and the non-zero return value causes my rake task to exit earlier than I'd like.

Is there any programatic resolution for my situation?

Thank you for your help; I've gone ahead and marked this question as answered as I think my particular case is an edge case.

Comment: Capistrano does use sh - both in default tasks and when you call something via run. You can pass a parameter to the run method, :shell => false, which will run it without the sh. I believe you can also set a global in your deploy.rb, i.e., set :shell, false.

Comment: It's been some time since your answer, and I tried to get this working with Capistrano 2.12.0. When I do like you explained, I get: "defining a task named `disable' would shadow an existing method with that name". Seems like some tasks are loaded twice? Any idea?

Comment: This command works, but one of my requires in `deploy.rb` failed: `require whenever/capistrano` (when I run it manually, it's okay)

Comment: is this still applicable for capistrano v3?

Comment: @SarahMei Thank you very much for this answer. It helped me fix a bug in my deploy script.

Answer (score 3):

For capistrano 3:

http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/capistrano-pure-ruby/

```
require 'capistrano/all'

  stages = "production"
  set :application, 'my_app_name'
  set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:capistrano/capistrano.git'
  set :deploy_to, '/var/www/'
  set :stage, :production
  role :app, %w{}

  require 'capistrano/setup'
  require 'capistrano/deploy'
  Dir.glob('capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }

  Capistrano::Application.invoke("production")
  Capistrano::Application.invoke("deploy")
```

Answer (score -1):

Jonathan, your mileage may vary by doing something like set(:shell, false) to stop capistrano running tasks in a sub-sh-shell.

Just a thought, feel free to ping me if you need a hand though.